# Absolute value in integrals leading to logs

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, logarithms, absolute-value

I know that when working with real numbers, the input for a logarithm cannot be negativea, and hence when taking the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$, we take the absolute value:
$$ \int{ \frac{1}{x}dx}=ln|x|+C$$

However, when I l[ook up the integral](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-indefinite-integral-of-1-xlnx) of $\frac{1}{x ln x}$ online, I get an absolute value in the outer expression but not the inner.
$$ \int{ \frac{1}{x ln x}dx}=ln| lnx|+C$$

Why isn't the inner one require an absolute value?

Comment: Because in the second integral, the function you're integrating has a ln(x) in it, so we already have to restrict ourselves to positive x just based on that.

Comment: The integrand should be $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$, right?
Note the missing x.